# How can I upload file and also include JSON data with Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, fetch-api

Hope you're having a good day. So I'm using Fetch API to upload files to server but I also want to include a string as JSON for my backend. But I'm unable to do so.

Right now this is what my upload-file function looks like. This works perfectly if I want to just upload a file and not include a string as JSON:

```
const uploadFile = ( e ) => {

    const uploadedFile = e.target.files[ 0 ];
    const formData     = new FormData();

    formData.append( 'data', uploadedFile );

    const rawResponse = await fetch( '/upload-file', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
    });
    
};

uploadFile();
```

Getting the file in my NodeJS backend with `req.files.data`;

But if I include a string as JSON and try to upload file then I get undefined in my NodeJS backend. This is how it looks like with string as JSON:

```
const uploadFile = ( e ) => {

    const uploadedFile = e.target.files[ 0 ];
    const formData     = new FormData();
    const str          = 'from client';

    formData.append( 'data', uploadedFile );

    const rawResponse = await fetch( '/upload-file', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: {
                file: formData,
                str 
          }
    });
    
};

uploadFile();
```

Now if I want to get the file in my backend with:

`req.files.file`, I get `undefined`.

`req.body`, I get `{ 'object Object': '' }`.

`req.files.data`, I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`.

`req.body.data`, I get `undefined`.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: you append it to formdata, not body

Comment: `formData.append( 'str', '["some JSON here"]' );`

Comment: awesome you guys. it worked. which one of your answers should I choose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you append it to `FormData`, not body

```
const uploadFile = ( e ) => {

    const uploadedFile = e.target.files[ 0 ];
    const formData     = new FormData();
    const str          = 'from client';

    formData.append( 'data', uploadedFile );
    formData.append( 'str', str );

    const rawResponse = await fetch( '/upload-file', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
    });
    
};

uploadFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append the value to the FormData object, same as you did with the file already

```
formData.append( 'str', '["some JSON here"]' );
```

And then keep sending just that object, `body: formData`

Comment: Unless the string is a hardcoded don't do this, rely on JSON.stringify(variable).

Comment: @LeonardoDrici that is true in general of course, but if the original question already refers to this as `const str = 'from client';`, this is probably not the issue to focus on here.