# React TS image upload as a single request

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file

I need to upload images to the server with the use of react TS, currently I have two types:

`Product.ts`

```
export type Product = {
    name: string;
    productId:string;
    price: number;
    manufacturer: string;
    model: string;
    year: Date;
    location: string;
    category: string;
    description: string;
    workedHours: number;
    state: string;
    hoursUnderPower: number;
    atlocalNorms: boolean;
    status: string;
    createdBy: UserInfo;
    productImages: ProductImage[];
}
```

`ProductImage.ts`

```
export type ProductImage = {
    productId: string;
    productImageId: string;
    productImageFileName: string;
    productImageUrlPath: string;
}
```

I can easily get the products with image data, but the issue arises with product creation and file conversion, in my api there is a method for image upload, but I do not want it to first create the product and then add images, as that will create products with no images(even for a split second)

I want to upload them together, which I can do with my Api call:
`POST JSON`

```
{
  "productId": "e58bf22d-bea6-48ad-f418-09dc4cd8174e",
  "name": "Name",
  "price": 120000,
  "manufacturer": "Huskvarna",
  "model": "I-765",
  "year": 2009,
  "location": "Maldives",
  "category": "Chainsaw",
  "description": "A hefty chainsaw",
  "workedHours": 1000,
  "state": "Used",
  "hoursUnderPower": 1000,
  "atLocalNorms": true,
  "status": "none",
  "dateCreated": "2024-03-25",
  "createdBy": "jdoe",
  "productImages": [
    {
      "productImageId": "4cb30793-d1ee-4eb3-d75a-08dc4cd81775",
      "productId": "e58bf22d-bea6-48ad-f418-09dc4cd8174e",
      "productImageFileName": "Namewithextension.jpg",
      "productImageUrlPath": "localhosturl"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I don't really understand how to convert the `const [images, setImage] = useState<File[]>([])` to product images, attach them to a product and then send them to the api?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I upload file and also include JSON data with Fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120374/how-can-i-upload-file-and-also-include-json-data-with-fetch-api)